# How to add new column in between two previous columns in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

How to add new column **in between** two previous columns of a table in Postgres?

Comment: The order of columns is not relevant in a relational database - just add it to the table - doesn't matter where it ends up. If you need to specify an order of columns in your `SELECT` - then just specify the column in the order you want

Comment: Why do you need that? It makes no sense.

Comment: You can't, not directly. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position

Comment: It is nice to see the result of a query like select * from  whatnot come out in a specific way. Also, can't you do an insert without using the column names? this would rely on the column ordering.

Answer (score 2):

You have to drop and create the whole table with the new column in between, if you want it so bad. There is no easy way.